# Selecting first NOT NULL column, then getting name of that column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, coalesce

I have a database table set up in the following way:

```
table
--------
id: 123
name: test
description: lorem ipsum
a: NULL
b: NULL
c: NULL
d: lorem ipsum
e: NULL
f: lorem ipsum
```

Then I have a variable on my PHP page, `$id = 123`

How can I return the **name** of the first NOT NULL column, searching in `a, b, c, d, e, f` only? So in this instance, the query would return `d` or `f` into a string. (**NOT** `lorem ipsum`)

Here's something I've tried for you to get a better understanding of what I need:

(as far as I know,  `COALESCE()` will "return the first non-NULL argument")

```
$cat = mysql_query("SELECT coalesce(a, b, c, d, e, f) FROM table WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1");
$cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat);
$cat = array_shift(array_values($cat));
```

The query above almost does what I want, it returns the information of the first NOT NULL column (so in this instance, it returns `lorem ipsum`)... What I need is the **NAME** of that column.

So then I tried `$cat = mysql_field_name($cat, 0);` (see below for info) - but apparently this needs to be ran on the query, not the string returned from `mysql_fetch_assoc`. So I tried doing exactly that and running `mysql_field_name` on the query, and it returns part of the original query (`coalesce(a, b, c, d, e, f)`) when I echo it. Weird huh?

([info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php) —`mysql_field_name` — Get the name of the specified field in a result)

For recap: The 3 lines of PHP I provided are working and provide information from a column, but I need a way to get the **NAME** of that column and store it into a string. Thanks

---

After following Gordon's method I changed the first line of my PHP in the example above (the query) to `$cat = mysql_query("select (case when a is not null then 'a' when b is not null then 'b' when c is not null then 'c' when d is not null then 'd' when e is not null then 'e' when f is not null then 'f' end) FROM directory WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1")` but it returns a boolean (so I can't run `mysql_fetch_assoc` as it isn't actually returning anything), I have checked all names of columns are correct etc.

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/214577). This code uses *very* outdated functions that are **no longer part of PHP**. You might want to (read: should really, without any excuses) step away from them.

Comment: yeah yeah I know, not got round to updating yet

Answer (score 1):

Just use `case`:

```
select (
         case 
               when a is not null then 'a'
               when b is not null then 'b'
               when c is not null then 'c'
               when d is not null then 'd'
               when e is not null then 'e'
               when f is not null then 'f'
         end
      )
```

Comment: this is returning a boolean for me, when I try to run `mysql_fetch_assoc` on the above query. I have slightly changed the query, `select (case when a is not null then 'a'
             when b is not null then 'b'
...
        end) FROM directory WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @RyanButterworth . . . This `case` expression should be returning a string.  I don't see how it could be returning a boolean.

Comment: Well it would suggest there is human error (typing the table names wrong etc) although I checked thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be with the help of array_filter ([array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter))
You can give it an array and without an callback, it will give you alle elements that evaluate to true. The column name remains so you can use the key function.
So something like this:

```
$keys = key(array_filter($cat))
```

And on $keys[0] you find your name.

Comment: The problem is that my original query is returning `coalesce(a, b, c, d, e, f)` - so when using your method `$keys[0]` would return `c`.... `$keys[1]` would return `o`.... `$keys[2]` would return `a`..... `$keys[3]` would return `l` etc etc etc... I'm pretty sure your method would work but my query is wrong, `coalesce()` isn't working properly...

Comment: What if you just use the sql query without coalesce and fetch the name in php? Then you can use this method. Or the method mention from @gordon. But this has the disadvantage that you are not so flexible. E.g. when the schema changes you need to adjust your query.